# How to drop all stored procedures at once in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently we use separate a drop statements for each stored procedure in the script file:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MySP]')   
  AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))  
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
```

Is there a way to drop them all at once, or maybe in a loop?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Something like (Found at [Delete All Procedures from a database using a Stored procedure in SQL Server](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/309.html)).

Just so by the way, this seems like a **VERY** dangerous thing to do, just a thought...

```
declare @procName varchar(500)
declare cur cursor 

for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'p'
open cur
fetch next from cur into @procName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    exec('drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')
    fetch next from cur into @procName
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Why do you think it is very dangerous?

Comment: For one, because it's missing an extra WHERE clause: for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'p' AND is_ms_shipped = 0

Comment: Works great, I use it when I accidentally write couple hundred sprocs to master instead of specific database.

Comment: BTW, add [ ] around the proc name in case you have any that are strange.  The Exec should look like this:
    exec('drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')

Comment: Fearless developers love dangerous scripts. Namaste.

Comment: This script is missing schema name and only works for objects that are dbo.

Comment: The script is only dangerous if you aren't sure of exactly what it will do. replace the 'drpo procedure' line with 'print @procName' and it will print a list of everything that will be dropped.

Answer (score 160):

I would prefer to do it this way:

- first generate the list of stored procedures to drop by inspecting the system catalog view:

  ```
  SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + '];'
  FROM sys.procedures p
  ```

  This generates a list of `DROP PROCEDURE` statements in your SSMS output window.
- copy that list into a new query window, and possibly adapt it / change it and then execute it

No messy and slow cursors, gives you the ability to check and double-check your list of procedure to be dropped before you actually drop it

Comment: I need this for deployment, so it has to be automatic.

Comment: I've really got to say that a cursor is way faster than copy and paste.

Comment: SQLSMO provides a rich set of objects to doing pretty much anything you can imagine with your databases. Its my preference for complex deployment and migration tasks. [link to overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx)

Comment: Superb answer, saved my lots of time.

Comment: This one is very useful, especially if you have accidentaly added SPs somewhere (like master) when you shouldn't have. Gives you a simple way of doing a clean up with a precheck.

Comment: Add shema name: select 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + s.name + '.' + p.NAME from sys.procedures p inner join sys.schemas s on p.schema_id = s.schema_id

Comment: A slight improvement would be to include the square brackets to catch any names with hyphens in.

SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.procedures p

Comment: Much prefer this way! Also very handy if you only want to remove a few or half or some subset of the procedures. If you tack on an "order by" you can sort it and better look through before dropping.

Comment: Just a quick note: I was curious whether this would generate `DROP` statements for the *all* databases on the server. It doesn't, it only generates them for the db in use... which is what I wanted.

Comment: Tack on a where clause to select just the ones you want to delete:
`SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.procedures p
WHERE p.name LIKE '%crud_%'`

Answer (score 116):

1. In the Object Explorer pane, select the Stored Procedures folder.
2. Press F7 (or from the main menu, choose View > Object Explorer Details).
3. Select all procedures **except the System Table**.
4. Press Delete button and select OK.

You can delete Tables or Views in the same manner.

Answer (score 13):

create below stored procedure in your db(from which db u want to delete sp's)

then right click on that procedure - click on Execute Stored Procedure..

then click ok.

```
create Procedure [dbo].[DeleteAllProcedures]
As 
declare @schemaName varchar(500)    
declare @procName varchar(500)
declare cur cursor
for select s.Name, p.Name from sys.procedures p
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE p.type = 'P' and is_ms_shipped = 0 and p.name not like 'sp[_]%diagram%'
ORDER BY s.Name, p.Name
open cur

fetch next from cur into @schemaName,@procName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
if @procName <> 'DeleteAllProcedures'
exec('drop procedure ' + @schemaName + '.' + @procName)
fetch next from cur into @schemaName,@procName
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Best answer! handles schemas too

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @sql=@sql+'drop procedure ['+name +'];' FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'p' AND  is_ms_shipped = 0

exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get drop statements for all stored procedures in a database
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE' + ' '
+ F.NAME + ';'
FROM SYS.objects AS F where type='P'

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql=''
SELECT @sql=@sql+'drop procedure ['+name +'];' FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'p' AND  is_ms_shipped = 0
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Code only answers are not appreciated. Post your code with little explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it work for me

```
DECLARE @spname sysname;
DECLARE SPCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P';
OPEN SPCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM SPCursor INTO @spname;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE ' + @spname);
FETCH NEXT FROM SPCursor INTO @spname;
END
CLOSE SPCursor;
DEALLOCATE SPCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DeleteProcCommand NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE Syntax_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + p.NAME
FROM sys.procedures p

OPEN Syntax_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Syntax_Cursor

INTO @DeleteProcCommand

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

EXEC (@DeleteProcCommand)

FETCH NEXT FROM Syntax_Cursor
INTO @DeleteProcCommand

END

CLOSE Syntax_Cursor

DEALLOCATE Syntax_Cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'DROP PROCEDURE dbo.'
  + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
' FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name LIKE N'spname%'
AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = N'dbo';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI compliant, without cursor

```
DECLARE @SQL national character varying(MAX) 
SET @SQL= ''

SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ N'DROP PROCEDURE "' + REPLACE(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, N'"', N'""') + N'"."' + REPLACE(SPECIFIC_NAME, N'"', N'""') + N'"; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 

WHERE (1=1) 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND ROUTINE_NAME NOT IN 
(
     'dt_adduserobject'
    ,'dt_droppropertiesbyid'
    ,'dt_dropuserobjectbyid'
    ,'dt_generateansiname'
    ,'dt_getobjwithprop'
    ,'dt_getobjwithprop_u'
    ,'dt_getpropertiesbyid'
    ,'dt_getpropertiesbyid_u'
    ,'dt_setpropertybyid'
    ,'dt_setpropertybyid_u'
    ,'dt_verstamp006'
    ,'dt_verstamp007'

    ,'sp_helpdiagrams'
    ,'sp_creatediagram'
    ,'sp_alterdiagram'
    ,'sp_renamediagram'
    ,'sp_dropdiagram'

    ,'sp_helpdiagramdefinition'
    ,'fn_diagramobjects'
    ,'sp_upgraddiagrams'
) 


ORDER BY SPECIFIC_NAME 


-- PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Without cursor, non-ansi compliant:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
, @lineFeed NVARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ;

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'DROP PROCEDURE ' + QUOTENAME(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(SPECIFIC_NAME) + N';' + @lineFeed
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
-- AND SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE 'sp[_]RPT[_]%'


AND ROUTINE_NAME NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT name FROM sys.procedures WHERE is_ms_shipped <> 0 
) 


ORDER BY SPECIFIC_NAME 


-- PRINT @sql 
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

By mixing the cursor and system procedure, we would have a optimized solution, as follow:

```
DECLARE DelAllProcedures CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT name AS procedure_name 
    FROM sys.procedures;
OPEN DelAllProcedures
DECLARE @ProcName VARCHAR(100)
FETCH NEXT 
FROM DelAllProcedures
INTO @ProcName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS!=-1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @command VARCHAR(100)
    SET @command=''
    SET @command=@command+'DROP PROCEDURE '+@ProcName
    --DROP PROCEDURE  @ProcName
    EXECUTE (@command)
    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM DelAllProcedures
    INTO @ProcName
END
CLOSE DelAllProcedures
DEALLOCATE DelAllProcedures
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSI compliant, without cursor

```
PRINT ('1.a. Delete stored procedures ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121));
GO
DECLARE @procedure NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @n CHAR(1)
SET @n = CHAR(10)
SELECT @procedure = isnull( @procedure + @n, '' ) +
'DROP PROCEDURE [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
FROM sys.procedures

EXEC sp_executesql @procedure
PRINT ('1.b. Stored procedures deleted ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121));
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @procName varchar(500)
declare cur cursor 

for SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.procedures p 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @procName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    exec( @procName )
    fetch next from cur into @procName
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```