# How to delete all stored procedures in SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have about 100 stored procedures, now I want to delete them all using T-SQL but I don't know how doing it.

So how to do it?

Comment: You can use DROP SP SP NAME. And get all the names of SP's using sysobjects.

Answer (score 2):

first generate the list of stored procedures to drop by inspecting the system catalog view:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '].[' + p.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.procedures p
```

This generates a list of DROP PROCEDURE statements in your SSMS output window.

copy that list into a new query window, and possibly adapt it / change it and then execute it
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610820/how-to-drop-all-stored-procedures-at-once-in-sql-server-database) :

Answer (score 1):

I would select all the procedure names from the procedures view and then run through a cursor deleting each of them. Be careful running that, it will delete all your procedures from the currently selected db.

```
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE procs cursor for
SELECT name FROM sys.procedures 

OPEN procs

FETCH NEXT FROM procs
INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXECUTE (' DROP PROCEDURE ' + @name + ';');

END

CLOSE procs;
DEALLOCATE procs;
```

Comment: @TienKenji - you cannot say all the `SP's` will be in `DBO` schema better not to have schema name hard coded

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple solution is enough:

```
select 'drop procedure ' + name from sys.objects where type = 'P'
```

and then just copy-paste the results to a query window + run it.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, expand the database tree, expand programming and select stored procedures. This should bring up a list of procedures in the Object Explorer Details. You will be able to select all the procedures there, then right click and delete.

If you need a T-SQL script, in the resultant pop-up, you can choose script

Comment: How select all the procedures?

Comment: Left click on first procedure, scroll down and left click last procedure, with shift key pressed.

Comment: You need click on procedures and then click F7, then you can select all procedures

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it without using loop is

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT @sql+=' exec Drop procedure ' + s.name + '.' + p.name
FROM   sys.procedures p
        JOIN sys.schemas s
            ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id 

--print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```